# How to use Django translated variable (trans) in template if statement

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am facing a prob in django. The following is my code snippet :

```
{% if pageName != 'My page Name' %}
  .....{{ then this }}
```

Now this works fine for English , Now when i translated my application in another language the `pageName` also changed according to that language. So the above logic is not working as it is hard coded English

So i have to try to implement  the logic with translated version of `'My page Name'`. But i cant use it directly in `if` like :

```
{% if pageName != trans 'My page Name' %}
```

So I thought of storing the translated version in another variable and then check with that variable like :

```
{%blocktrans%} "My page Name" {{myvar}} {%endblocktrans%}
{% if pageName != myvar %}
```

But this is also not working `myvar`takes the value `"My page Name"` , not the translated version of it.

Any clue how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about {% trans "My page Name" as myvar %} ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use trans template tag but this way

```
{% trans "My page Name" as myvar %} 
{% if pageName != myvar %}
...
```

See [trans template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag)